# I dont want Navigation bar overlays other elements in page. CSS

Tags: html, css

I am doing beginner projects.
i put 2 div, one for headder and one for the "body" of the page. after styling the header the other div is just behind the header div and i cannot change it no matter what. all i want is the header to be some kind of "nothing go behind" and the body div to be under it.

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="beauty.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="heading">
          <h1>This is Calculator</h1>
        </div>
        
        <div id="gutt">
          <p>check number here</p>
          <input type="number">
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
    ```
    
    **CSS**
    ```
    body {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    #heading {
      display: block;
      background-color: blue;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0%;
    }
````

Comment: Remove `position: absolute;` in css and you can see your `id="gutt"`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `position:absolute`of your #heading section.
Corrected Codes:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#heading {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
}
```

```html
<body>
      <div id="heading">
        <h1>This is Calculator</h1>
      </div>
      
      <div id="gutt">
        <p>check number here</p>
        <input type="number">
      </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: first of all thank you alot! what i dont get, it is how you set an div that automatically cant be another div behind it...

Comment: No, that isn't the convenient way to do it. Actually I think you have added the position:absolutely for some reason. I have edited the previous code here. Please have a check.

Comment: but then the nav bar isn't stuck to the top

Comment: you mean, when you do scrolling? Without scrolling, it should be fine. Can you share some screenshots?